# How can i count a score when i compared 2 spans.Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have 3 spans.2 in 3 spans has an alphabet for each span.The last span is the blank for a result of 2 spans which is compared.
I want to put the result ,which 2 in 3 spans were compared and if that 2 spans has the same alphabet a result is 1, into the last span.
how can i do that ???

Comment: Please show ,what have  you tried ?? and where are you facing problem :)

Comment: Could you be a little more clear or provide some relevant code? It sounds kind of like you want 3 `<span>`s, two of which have a letter each, and the third `<span>` should contain a `1` if the first two have the same letter. Correct? But what if they're not the same?

Comment: @flowstoneknight>> exactly
if they're not same the result is 0.

Comment: thank you very much >> @Abdul Jabbar to understood my bad english haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what i could understand.. you have three spans, two with alphabet and one empty..

```
<span id="span1">a</span>
<span id="span2">a</span>
<span id="span3"></span>
```

Now you want to compare first two spans and if they have same alphabet then third one will contain 1, otherwise im putting a 0 there:

```
if(document.getElementById('span1').innerHTML == document.getElementById('span2').innerHTML) {
    document.getElementById('span3').innerHTML = '1';
}
else{
    document.getElementById('span3').innerHTML = '0';
}
```

**[See the DEMO here](http://jsfiddle.net/KTrEp/74/)**